# radio buton y textarea en un cuestionario dinamico

Tags: php, mysql, radiobutton

estoy creando un cuestionario dinamico con MYSQL y PHP 7. en una paguina creo mis preguntas y mi cuestionario y las guardo en MYSQL y en otra paguina las muestro realizando una llamada a la base de datos para traerme las preguntas.

solo que tengo un inconveniente, al hacer llamar las preguntas quiero que po cada pregunta me mande 2 radiosbutton y 2 textarea.

lo cual lo realice de la siguiente manera.

```html
 <table>
            <tr>
                <!--Mostramos el titulo de la encuesta-->
                <td colspan="2"> <h3><?php echo $titulo; ?></h3></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
            </tr>
            <?php
            //consulta que captura el texto , id de la tabla respuestas
            $sql = "SELECT texto,id FROM respuestas WHERE idenc='$id'";
            $sql = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
            //ahora recorremos los datos texto, id que estan vinculadas a la cuenta seleccionada
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                $texto = $row["texto"];
                $idres = $row["id"];
               
       //añiado los radiobuttons y los textarea          
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td width="50"><?php echo $idres; ?></td>
                <td width="470"><?php echo $texto; ?></td>
                <td> SI <input type="radio" name="SI" value="<?php echo $idres; ?>"></td>
                <td> NO <input type="radio" name="NO" value="<?php echo $idres; ?>"></td>
                <td><textarea name="comentarios" rows="5" cols="20">Escribe aquí tus Hallasgos</textarea></td>
                <td><textarea name="comentarios" rows="5" cols="20">Escribe aquí tus Acciones Correctivas</textarea></td>
                
           </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <tr>
```

solo que de esta manera solo me permite contestar dos preguntas y no todas las preguntas de la encuesta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que tienes intercambiados los atributos value y name

name es el nombre del campo, como solo hay names si y no solo te permitirá contestar 2 veces

en name debes colocar el idres y value de cada campo es Si o No dependiendo del valor del radio button

Comment: ok, entiendo solo una consulta como puedo pasar el valor seleccionado en el radiobutton a la base de datos

Comment: Para eso debes colocar los campos del formulario dentro de una etiqueta form, en el atributo action debes especificar el archivo que se encargara de guardar los datos. En ese archivo debes escribir el codigo para el guardado de los datos. Aqui un ejemplo viejo pero sencillo: http://myfamilystudio.blogspot.mx/2012/06/guardar-datos-una-base-de-datos-mysql.html